# How can I make iChat not pause iTunes when I start a screen sharing session?

Tags: macos, mac, itunes, ichat, screen-sharing

It's annoying.</filler-text>

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty unsatisfactory answer, but you can actually reduce the pause to just a momentary blip by assigning a "play iTunes" AppleScript alert to the "A/V Chat Started" event (in Preferences -> Alerts). Such an AppleScript would read:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    play
end tell
```

But hopefully someone will discover a better way.

Comment: Clever and not entirely bad.